# How to edit href of button on magento homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I was a magento dev for some years but stopped for a couple of years. Now back and was stuck at how magento (architecture works).

Question is:
How to find the href of a submit button on a magento homepage?

Comment: Does this button submit a form, or does it have an onclick event?

Comment: What kind of button is it? Add to cart? Newsletter submit? Custom button?

Answer (score 0):

this will where the template button is located.

```
Log into the magento back-end admin
Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
```

Remember to clear your cache.

Comment: I think its a javascript generated button since there is no form action in its parent